# Can you work with files in a Dropbox folder when Dropbox isn't running?

Tags: macos, sync, dropbox

I'm working on a large video project that involves some shared Dropbox folders. Because the folders are too big to fit on my internal hard drive, I created a separate user account on my Mac and configured Dropbox in that account to store its files on an external drive (and I marked those folders as being offline via selective sync in my regular user account).

I plan to use my regular account to work with the files themselves, accessing them directly from the external drive, when the second Mac user account is not running.

Will this work? In other words, can you edit/add/remove files from a Dropbox folder when Dropbox is not running, and then log back into the user account that has Dropbox configured to use the files in that location and have those modified files sync properly?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, dropbox will sync the changes next time you login in to that user account.

I use a similar setup for audio recording.